# Why "a==b" in C is compiled to "xor; j; sltu" in assembly? - Why instruction after unconditional jump?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, compiler-construction, mips

I want to see how `==` is compiled in C. Thus I try a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int a,int b) {
    return a==b; // NOTE THIS
}

int main(void) {
    int a,b,c;
    scanf("%d", &a,&b);
    printf("%d", f(a,b));
}
```

Here is the attempt on Godbolt. It is very counter-intuitive...

[image]

Question:

1. Why instruction after unconditional jump? IMHO the sltu will never be executed.
2. Why one single `xor` enough to express `==`? IMHO need xor + sltu together.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, just ignoring the fact that you're passing two `int*` to a `scanf` call whose format only demands one?

Comment: As for (1), this is a *branch delay slot*.  The `sltu` instruction is executed before the branch takes effect.  As for (2), both `xor` and `sltu` are indeed used together, see the response to (1).

Comment: [Why does this load instruction come after a jump?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53715539/995714), [What is the point of delay slots?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15375084/995714)

Comment: Also unrelated, the function is not called at all, it is inlined. However, because it is global, the compiler needed to include it.

Comment: Related: [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444)

Comment: @WhozCraig fuz phuclv thebusybee PeterCordes Thanks friends! I fully get it.